# Getting images and names in recycler view from api using retrofit shows blank screen in app android studio

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit

i'm developing an app wherein i'm using retrofit library to fetch api in my app. I want to get list of images and names from the api in recycler view. I have set the recycler view lyout manager as grid layout.

The problem is that when i try to run the fragment for loading these image list the screen is showing blank. on the debug log it's showing inceasing code cache capacity to 2 MB but the output on mobile screen is blank.

I'm getting response from the api in the logcat but not on app.

this is adapter class

```
public class ProductCategoriesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductCategoriesAdapter.CategoriesViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<CategoryModel> categoryList;

    public ProductCategoriesAdapter(Context context, List<CategoryModel> categoryList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.categoryList = categoryList;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ProductCategoriesAdapter.CategoriesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.all_category_item, parent, false);
        return new ProductCategoriesAdapter.CategoriesViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProductCategoriesAdapter.CategoriesViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.categoryName.setText(categoryList.get(position).getProductCategoryName());

        String url = categoryList.get(position).getProductImage() ;
        Glide.with(context)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(url)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.sample_product_img)
                .centerInside()
                .into(holder.categoryImage);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return categoryList.size();
    }

    class CategoriesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        CircleImageView categoryImage;
        TextView categoryName;

        CategoriesViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            categoryImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_image);
            categoryName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_name);

        }
    }
}
```

in getProductCatList method i'm getting response and setting the list to recyclerview with adapter and calling this method on oncreateview method of fragment

```
 private void getProductCatList() {

        categoryList = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2));
        adapter = new ProductCategoriesAdapter(getActivity(), categoryList);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Call<AllCategoriesModel> call = RetrofitProductClient.getInstance().getApi().getAllCategories();

try{
    call.enqueue(new Callback<AllCategoriesModel>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<AllCategoriesModel> call, 
    Response<AllCategoriesModel> response) {
                                                                                
    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                                                                      
   categoryList = Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getProductCategories();
                        adapter = new ProductCategoriesAdapter(getContext(), categoryList);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    } else {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        StyleableToast.makeText(getContext(), "failed " + response.message(), R.style.StyledToast).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<AllCategoriesModel> call, Throwable t) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    StyleableToast.makeText(getContext(), t.getLocalizedMessage(), R.style.StyledToast).show();
                }
            });
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            StyleableToast.makeText(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()), e.getLocalizedMessage(), R.style.StyledToast).show();
        }
    }
```

the following is debug log after getting response from api and the mobile screen is blank

```
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: <-- END HTTP (2222-byte body)
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: <-- END HTTP (2222-byte body)
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: <-- END HTTP (2222-byte body)
I/zygote64: Compiler allocated 7MB to compile void android.widget.TextView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
I/Toast: Show toast from OpPackageName:com.test.myapp, PackageName:com.test.myapp
I/zygote64: Compiler allocated 6MB to compile void android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals()
```

what should i do. Can anybody please help

Comment: Add code of adapter and where you are setting it .

Answer (score 0):

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
// [...]
adapter = new ProductCategoriesAdapter(getContext(), categoryList);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

It seems like you set an adapter to the recyclerview but create a new one every time and your recyclerview doesn't know about it.

Instead, try adding all the new items to your `categoryList` and then notify your adapter like this:

```
categoryList.clear()
categoryList.addAll(myNewItems)
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```